# Unable to see the Terraform provider file after running terraform init

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm, terraform-template-file

I am stuck in a path where when I run terraform init. the provider is not getting downloaded and it gives me no error. I am using the main.tf file and in it, I have provider "azurerm" syntax only. So when I run the terraform init I get the below output only and I see nowhere the terraform provider file getting initialized or getting downloaded. Logged in and authenticated to Azure login page too.

Terraform Code> terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.

Comment: You are probably running the command in the wrong directory, at least that is what happens to me occasionally. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terraform creates a hidden folder to store the provider. Make sure you set your OS permissions to see hidden files and folders.

From the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/cli/init):

> A hidden .terraform directory, which Terraform uses to manage cached provider plugins and modules, record which workspace is currently active, and record the last known backend configuration in case it needs to migrate state on the next run. This directory is automatically managed by Terraform, and is created during initialization.